# Oh Snap! Build request failed with message: Error: ENOENT, unlink

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to run the simple BlackBerry webworks  application on my ripple emulator.I am able to run it on ripple emulator and can see the proper UI. If I will package and build the app through Ripple then i am getting the error as follows:

"Oh Snap! Build request failed with message: Error: ENOENT, unlink"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe its a timing issue with the first time you click the build button. Hit 'Build' again and it will work.